# Prove that the integer $A= 3^{3n+3}- 36n - 27$ is divisible by $169$ for all positive integers $n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$A=3^{3n+3}- 36n - 27$ is divisible by $169$

So, would the first step, or basic step, be n= alpha S(alpha)=T?

How would the set up for the second step, or inductive step, be?

Comment: are you sure that your problem is correctly typed?

Comment: The current version $3^3 n + 3 - 36 n - 27$ is wrong.  So are $3^{3n}+3-36n-27$ and $3^{3n+3}-36n-27$.

Comment: @.L.Vasquez. It looks certain that your Q is not typed right.

Comment: $3^{3n+3} - 36 n - 27$ is divisible by $9$ for all $n$, and by $16$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: Use { } to group things you want to go in the superscript.

Comment: But $3^{3n+3} - 36 n - 27$ is divisible by $169$ if and only if $n$ is divisible by $169$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you for the tip, I could not figure it out!

Comment: So, would I state that A is divisible by 169, is and only if A is divisible by 16 in the second step?

Comment: First you should get the correct question to work on.  There's no point in trying to prove a false statement.

Comment: Ah, maybe it's $3^{3n+3} - 26 n - 27$.  That one is divisible by $169$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your expression be $A_n=...$

Step 1:
Show that $A_1$ is divisible by 169.

Step 2:
Suppose that the statement is true for $A_n$. Find an expression for $A_{n+1}$ in terms of $n$. You want to show that $A_{n+1}$ and $A_n$ are related in a way that gives the multiple of 169.

Note that the expression for $A_n$ can be rewritten as $3^{3n+3}=A_n+26n+27$

Consider $A_{n+1}=3^{3(n+1)+3}-26(n+1)-27=3^{3n+3+3}-26n-26-27=3^3\times 3^{3n+3}-26n-53$

So $A_{n+1}=27\times (A_n+26n+27)-26n-53$

You have already supposeed that $A_n$ is a multiple of $169$ so rewrite $A_n=169m$

See where that takes you...

Comment: So, why don't you plug in (n+1) in "26n"?

Comment: Well spotted - not a deliberate error...

Answer (score 0):

I found the claim surprising, so I checked for n = 0 (true) and n = 1 (false). If it had been true for n = 1 and at least n = 2, I would have made a table of $3^{3n+3}$ = $27^{n+1}$ modulo 169 and checked that the result grows by 36 (modulo 169) until the values repeat.

The values are: 27, 53, 79, 105, ... Looks suspiciously like growth by 26.

26 x 27 = 702 = 4 x 169 + 26. So indeed $3^{3n+3}$ modulo 169 grows by 26 when n grows by 1, so the correct theorem is $3^{3n+3} = 26n + 27$ (modulo 169).

Comment: Shouldn't the 26 be a 36?